# Python's range() function not looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I tried to make a 'random' text program with 2 possible outputs, randomization works but `range()` isn't working. I always make some stupid mistakes so don't go hard one me over some stupid small thing pls

```
import time
import pyautogui
import random


time.sleep(2)
for i in range(50):
    if int(random.randint(1,2)) == 1:
        pyautogui.typewrite('bruh1')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        random.randint(1,2)
    elif int(random.randint(1,2)) == 2:
        pyautogui.typewrite('bruh2')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        random.randint(1,2)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `x = random.randint(1, 2)` instead of trying to call `x()`, which shouldn't work?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy no, thank you, its working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x is the random number returned by random.randint(). Not sure calling x() is the right thing. Can you please have a closer look at that part?

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
import pyautogui
import random


def typewrite(text):
    pyautogui.typewrite(text)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


for _ in range(50): # I use _ for variable if don't use it
    x = random.randint(0,1) # return 0 or 1 of type int
    if x: # if x is 1
        typewrite('bruh1')
    else: # if x is 0
        typewrite('bruh2')
```